# Are Databases and Functional Programming at odds?

Tags: sql, database, functional-programming, lisp

I've been a web developer for some time now, and have recently started learning some functional programming. Like others, I've had some significant trouble applying many of these concepts to my professional work. For me, the primary reason for this is that FP's goal of remaining stateless seems quite at odds with the fact that most web development work I've done has been heavily tied to databases, which are very data-centric.

One thing that made me a much more productive developer on the OOP side of things was the discovery of object-relational mappers like MyGeneration d00dads for .Net, Class::DBI for perl, ActiveRecord for ruby, etc. This allowed me to stay away from writing insert and select statements all day, and to focus on working with the data easily as objects. Of course, I could still write SQL queries when their power was needed, but otherwise it was abstracted nicely behind the scenes.

Now, turning to functional programming, it seems like many of the FP web frameworks like Links require writing a lot of boilerplate SQL code, as in [this example](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/links/examplessrc/dictionary/dict-suggest-update.links). Weblocks seems a little better, but it seems to use kind of an OOP model for working with data, and still requires code to be manually written for each table in your database as in [this example](http://www.bitbucket.org/S11001001/weblocks-dev/src/3ca71e2dfdd3/examples/weblocks-clsql-demo/src/model/). I suppose you use some code generation to write these mapping functions, but that seems decidedly un-lisp-like.

(Note I have not looked at Weblocks or Links extremely closely, I may just be misunderstanding how they are used.)

So the question is, for the database access portions (which I believe are pretty large) of web application, or other development requiring interface with a SQL database we seem to be forced down one of the following paths:

1. Don't use functional programming.
2. Access data in an annoying, un-abstracted way that involves manually writing a lot of SQL or SQL-like code a la Links.
3. Force our functional language into a pseudo-OOP paradigm, thus removing some of the elegance and stability of true functional programming.

Clearly, none of these options seem ideal.  Has anyone found a way to circumvent these issues? Is there really even an issue here?

Note: I personally am most familiar with LISP on the FP front, so if you want to give any examples and know multiple FP languages, LISP would probably be the preferred language of choice.

PS: For issues specific to other aspects of web development see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292033/is-functional-programming-relevant-to-web-development).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218190/is-functional-to-relational-mapping-easier-than-object-to-relational

Comment: Check out ClojureQL and HaskellDB. They are abstraction layers utilizing relational algebra.

Comment: You're starting out with the wrong premise. Functional programming is all about explicitly and sanely managing state. They work very well with databases, in fact.

Comment: SQL is one of the most successful functional-programming focused languages, I don't think that there is any inherent difficulty.

Comment: Your #2 and #3 are a false dichotomy. Writing raw SQL is not something that should necessarily be avoided, and abstractions over a database need not necessarily be OOP-esque.

Comment: agree with @Masse, if you want to focus on business logic, use a lib to wrap the details. functional programming is about separate the logic from the outside world. and outside world interaction is unavoidable.

Comment: GUN claims to be a functional reactive database: https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/graphs

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all, I would not say that CLOS (Common Lisp Object System) is "pseudo-OO".  It is first class OO.

Second, I believe that you should use the paradigm that fits your needs.

You cannot statelessly store data, while a function is flow of data and does not really need state.

If you have several needs intermixed, mix your paradigms.  Do not restrict yourself to only using the lower right corner of your toolbox.

Comment: just for fun, I thought I'd mention datalog which attempts to be a more stateless database. it records all actions, such as "user likes post 1233." These actions resolve to the true state of the database. The key is that queries are just facts rather than mutation...

Answer (score 84):

Coming at this from the perspective of a database person, I find that front-end developers try too hard to find ways to make databases fit their model rather than considering the most effective ways to use databases which are not object oriented or functional but relational and using set-theory. I have seen this generally result in poorly performing code. Further, it creates code that is difficult to performance tune.

When considering database access there are three main considerations — data integrity (why all business rules should be enforced at the database level and not through the user interface), performance, and security. SQL is written to manage the first two considerations more effectively than any front-end language, because it is specifically designed to do that. The task of a database is far different than the task of a user interface. Is it any wonder that the type of code that is most effective in managing the task is conceptually different?

Also, databases hold information critical to the survival of a company. Is it any wonder that businesses aren't willing to experiment with new methods when their survival is at stake? Heck, many businesses are unwilling to even upgrade to new versions of their existing database! So there is in inherent conservatism in database design, and it is deliberately that way.

I wouldn't try to write T-SQL or use database design concepts to create your user-interface, why would you try to use your interface language and design concepts to access my database? Because you think SQL isn't fancy (or new) enough? Or you don't feel comfortable with it? Just because something doesn't fit the model you feel most comfortable with, doesn't mean it is bad or wrong. It means that it is different and probably different for a legitimate reason. You use a different tool for a different task.

Comment: "SQL is written to manage the first two considerations more effectively than any front end language." Oh really? Why, then, is it that SQL constraints still cannot do things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616463/can-an-sql-constraint-be-used-to-prevent-a-particular-value-being-changed-when-a)?

Comment: But a trigger can, that's the one of the main purposes of triggers to be able to handle complex constraints.

Comment: I would move your last paragraph so that it's the leading paragraph.  Very good point, which echoes what others are also urging, which is a multi-paradigm approach (not one-size-fits-all).

Answer (score 33):

You should look at the paper "Out of the Tar Pit" by Ben Moseley and Peter Marks, available here: ["Out of the Tar Pit" (Feb. 6, 2006)](http://www.curtclifton.net/storage/papers/MoseleyMarks06a.pdf)

It is a modern classic which details a programming paradigm/system called Functional-Relational Programming. While not directly relating to databases, it discusses how to isolate interactions with the outside world (databases, for example) from the functional core of a system.

The paper also discusses how to implement a system where the internal state of the application is defined and modified using a relational algebra, which obviously is related to relational databases.

This paper will not give an an exact answer to how to integrate databases and functional programming, but it will help you design a system to minimize the problem.

Comment: What a great paper. The link you give is broken (temporarily?), but I found the paper also at http://shaffner.us/cs/papers/tarpit.pdf

Comment: @queque The original link is still dead. I put the new link into Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 26):

1. Functional languages do not have the goal to remain stateless, they have the goal to make management of state explicit. For instance, in Haskell, you can consider the State monad as the heart of "normal" state and the IO monad a representation of state which must exist outside of the program. Both of these monads allow you to (a) explicitly represent stateful actions and (b) build stateful actions by composing them using referentially transparent tools.
2. You reference a number of ORMs, which, per their name, abstract databases as sets of objects. Truely, this is not what the information in a relational database represents! Per its name, it represents relational data. SQL is an algebra (language) for handling relationships on a relational data set and is actually quite "functional" itself. I bring this up so as to consider that (a) ORMs are not the only way to map database information, (b) that SQL is actually a pretty nice language for some database designs, and (c) that functional languages often have relational algebra mappings which expose the power of SQL in an idiomatic (and in the case of Haskell, typechecked) fashion.

I would say most lisps are a poor man's functional language. It's fully capable of being used according to modern functional practices, but since it doesn't require them the community is less likely to use them. This leads to a mixture of methods which can be highly useful but certainly obscures how pure functional interfaces can still use databases meaningfully.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think the stateless nature of fp languages is a problem with connecting to databases. Lisp is a non-pure functional programming language so it shouldn't have any problem dealing with state. And pure functional programming languages like Haskell have ways of dealing with input and output that can be applied to using databases.

From your question it seems like your main problem lies in finding a good way to abstract away the record-based data you get back from your database into something that is lisp-y (lisp-ish?) without having to write a lot of SQL code. This seems more like a problem with the tooling/libraries than a problem with the language paradigm. If you want to do pure FP maybe lisp isn't the right language for you. Common lisp seems more about integrating good ideas from oo, fp and other paradigms than about pure fp. Maybe you should be using Erlang or Haskell if you want to go the pure FP route.

I do think the 'pseudo-oo' ideas in lisp have their merit too. You might want to try them out. If they don't fit the way you want to work with your data you could try creating a layer on top of Weblocks that allows you to work with your data the way you want. This might be easier than writing everything yourself.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Lisp expert. I'm mostly interested in programming languages and have been playing with Lisp/CLOS, Scheme, Erlang, Python and a bit of Ruby. In daily programming life I'm still forced to use C#.

Comment: Erlang's not pure FP by any definition of the word. You write erlang by creating lots of processes (all running in parallel) which send messages to eachother, much like objects in, say, smalltalk. So from a high-level perspective, it might even seem somewhat OO-ish, and definitely has state. If you zoom in (into the code running inside a process) it looks more functional, but still isn't purely functional, as you can send messages (and hence do I/O etc) from anyplace you want, as well as storing "global variables" (global to the process, inside something called the "process dict".)

Comment: @Amadiro "definitely has state". Of course it does. We always have state. The problem is not state, it is _mutable state_. A good part of "functional programming" is about getting rid of state representations that are brittle (e.g. object instances that are changed by other processes while we hold a reference to them, in an non-transactional way to add insult to injury). Erlang has non-mutable state and so hits this criteria of functional programming. And thus: Databases of whatever kind are never a problem. Database _updates_ are a problem (see also the nasty _assert_ in Prolog).

Answer (score 16):

If your database doesn't destroy information, then you can work with it in a functional manner consistent with "pure functional" programming values by working in functions of the entire database as a value.

If at time T the database states that "Bob likes Suzie", and you had a function likes which accepted a database and a liker, then so long as you can recover the database at time T you have a pure functional program that involves a database. e.g.

```
# Start: Time T
likes(db, "Bob")
=> "Suzie"
# Change who bob likes
...
likes(db "Bob")
=> "Alice"
# Recover the database from T
db = getDb(T)
likes(db, "Bob")
=> "Suzie"
```

To do this you can't ever throw away information you might use (which in all practicality means you cannot throw away information), so your storage needs will increase monotonically. But you can start to work with your database as a linear series of discrete values, where subsequent values are related to the prior ones through transactions.

This is the major idea behind [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/), for example.

Comment: Nice. I didn't even know about Datomic. See also: [rationale for Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/rationale.html).

Answer (score 13):

Not at all.  There are a genre of databases known as 'Functional Databases', of which [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/) is perhaps the most accessible example.  The basic principle is that functional programming is declarative, so it can be optimised.  You can implement a join using [List Comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) on persistent collections and the query optimiser can automagically work out how to implement the disk access.

Mnesia is written in [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) and there is at least one web framework ([Erlyweb](http://erlyweb.org/)) available for that platform.  Erlang is inherently parallel with a shared-nothing threading model, so in certain ways it lends itself to scalable architectures.

Comment: I don't think that's much of a solution. There are object-oriented databases too, but usually, you want to connect to a plain old relational SQL database.

Comment: You still have an impedance mismatch with OO languages and databases in much the same way as you have a functional-SQL impedance mismatch.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells I will arbitrarily state that this impedance mismatch is a figment of the imagination of people with hammers who need everything to be nails. Very thin layers and knowledge about SQL can elegantly go a long way, hence [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) and similar shims.

Answer (score 6):

I'm most comfortable with Haskell. The most prominent Haskell web framework (comparable to Rails and Django) is called Yesod. It seems to have a pretty cool, type-safe, multi-backend ORM. Have a look at the [Persistance chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) in their book.

Answer (score 6):

A database is the perfect way to keep track of state in a stateless API. If you subscribe to REST, then your goal is to write stateless code that interacts with a datastore (or some other backend) that keeps track of state information in a transparent way so that your client doesn't have to.

The idea of an Object-Relational Mapper, where you import a database record as an object and then modify it, is just as applicable and useful to functional programming as it is to object oriented programming. The one caveat is that functional programming does not modify the *object* in place, but the database API can allow you to modify the *record* in place. The control flow of your client would look something like this:

- Import the record as an object (the database API can lock the record at this point),
- Read the object and branch based on its contents as you like,
- Package a new object with your desired modifications,
- Pass the new object to the appropriate API call which updates the record on the database.

The database will update the record with your changes. Pure functional programming might disallow reassigning variables *within the scope of your program*, but your database API can still allow in-place updates.

Answer (score 2):

Databases and Functional Programming can be fused.

for example:

Clojure is a functional programming language based on relational database theory.

```
               Clojure -> DBMS, Super Foxpro
                   STM -> Transaction，MVCC
Persistent Collections -> db, table, col
              hash-map -> indexed data
                 Watch -> trigger, log
                  Spec -> constraint
              Core API -> SQL, Built-in function
              function -> Stored Procedure
             Meta Data -> System Table
```

Note: In the latest spec2, spec is more like RMDB. 
see: [spec-alpha2 wiki: Schema-and-select](https://github.com/clojure/spec-alpha2/wiki/Schema-and-select)

I advocate: Building a relational data model on top of hash-map to achieve a combination of NoSQL and RMDB advantages. This is actually a reverse implementation of posgtresql.

Duck Typing: If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.

**If clojure's data model like a RMDB, clojure's facilities like a RMDB and clojure's data manipulation like a RMDB, clojure must be a RMDB.**

[Clojure is a functional programming language based on relational database theory](https://github.com/linpengcheng/PurefunctionPipelineDataflow/blob/master/doc/Clojure_is_FP_based_on_RMDB.md)

[Everything is RMDB](https://github.com/linpengcheng/PurefunctionPipelineDataflow/blob/master/doc/Everything_is_RMDB.md)

[Implement relational data model and programming based on hash-map (NoSQL)](https://github.com/linpengcheng/PurefunctionPipelineDataflow/blob/master/doc/relational_model_on_hashmap.md)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that functional programming languages are popular in data science applications is their natural fit with the relational data model.  Many functional programming languages have [comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), which are isomorphic with a relational query language such as SQL (for further details see below).

Because comprehensions are mathematically isomorphic with SQL, we can map directly from a comprehension to an equivalent SQL query.  Functional programming languages such as Scala, have *functional-relational mapping* toolkits, such as [Slick](https://scala-slick.org/doc/stable/introduction.html).  Because of the 1-1 mapping between comprehensions and SQL queries, functional-relational mapping avoids many of the problems of object-relational mapping (see the [Object-Relational Impedance Mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch)).

Comprehensions express a succinct way to filter values using a predicate, and/or map the values through a function, resulting in another collection.  They can also be used to join collections using a Cartesian product.  When the collection is a set of flat tuples, each of which are the same length, then these operations are mathematically equivalent to SQL queries; we can think of each tuple as a row of data, and each set as a relation (implemented by a table in a RDBMS).

For example, consider the following Python implementation of a student relation (a set of tuples):

```py
# Student tuples
smith = ('Smith', 17, 1, 'CS')
brown = ('Brown', 8, 2, 'CS')

# The student relation
students = {smith, brown}

# The attributes of a student

def students_name(s):
    return s[0]
    
def students_student_number(s):
    return s[1]
```

We can then query the data using Python set comprehensions:

```py
{s for s in students if students_name(s) == 'Smith'}
```

which is equivalent to the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.name = "Smith";
```

We can also implement joins,

```py
grades = {
   (17, 'python',  'A'), 
   (17, 'algebra', 'B'), 
   (17, 'algebra', 'A'),
}

def grades_student_number(g):
    return g[0]

def grades_mark(g):
    return g[2]

{(students_name(s), grades_mark(g)) for s in students for g in grades if students_name(s) == 'Smith' and students_student_number(s) == grades_student_number(g)}
```

with equivalent SQL:

```sql
SELECT students.name, grades.mark FROM students, grades WHERE students.name = "Smith" AND students.student_number = grades.student_number;
```

For more details see [these notes](https://nbviewer.org/github/phelps-sg/python-bigdata/blob/master/src/main/ipynb/relational-python.ipynb).