# What is side effects in functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

I am learning Java 8 newly , i see one definition related to functional programming which is "A program created using **only pure functions** , **No Side effects** allowed".

One of side effects is "Modifying a data structure in place".

i don't understand this line because at last some where we need to speak with database for storing or retrieving or updating the data.

modifying database is not functional means how we will speak with database in functional programming ?

Comment: Look up the IO Monad.

Comment: In the context of Java 8, you don’t. You express operations in a functional way if this has a benefit and resort to other programming styles otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Modifying a data structure structure in place" means you directly manipulate the input datastructure (i.e. a List). "Pure functions" mean

- the result is only a function of it's input and not some other hidden state
- the function can be applied multiple times on the same input producing the same result. It will not change the input.

In Object Oriented Programming, you define behaviour of objects. Behaviour could be to provide read access to the state of the object, write access to it, or both. When combining operations of different concerns, you could introduce side effects.

For example a Stack and it's `pop()` operation. It will produce different results for every call because it changes the state of the stack.

In functional programming, you apply functions to immutable values. Functions represent a flow of data, not a change in state. So functions itself are stateless. And the result of a function is either the original input or a different value than the input, but never a modified input.

OO also knows functions, but those aren't *pure* in all cases, for example sorting: In non-functional programming you rearrange the elements of a list in the original datastructure ("in-place"). In Java, this is what Collections.sort()` does.

In functional programming, you would apply the sort function on an input value (a List) and thereby produce a new value (a new List) with sorted values. The function itself has no state and the state of the input is not modified.

So to generalize: *given the same input value, applying a function to this value produces the same result value*

Regarding the database operations. The contents of the database itself represent a state, which is the combination of all its stored values, tables etc (a "snapshot"). Of course you could apply a function to this data producing new data. Typically you store results of operations back to the db, thus changing the state of the entire system, but that doesn't mean you change the state of the function nor it's input data. Reapplying the function again, doesn't violate the pure-function constraints, because you apply the data to new input data. But looking at the entire *system* as a "datastructure" would violate the constraint, because the function application changes the state of the "input".

So the entire database system could hardly be considered *functional*, but of course you could operate on the *data* in a functional way.

But Java allows you to do both (OO and FP) and even mix both paradigms, so you could choose whatever approach fits your needs best.

or to quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330371/are-databases-and-functional-programming-at-odds)

> If you have several needs intermixed, mix your paradigms. Do not
>   restrict yourself to only using the lower right corner of your
>   toolbox.